# how to get text field value for javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, instagram

I need create a page like when user input the instagram user id in my form text field after clicked submit button text field value will be pass to the javascript. and show the profile pic of user without going to another page,. i'm using instagram token for that.

```js
var access_token = "2898196001.5b9e1e6.d2d96de78ffc4a14ade75dd6c7a07ff9";   
var user_id = "18428658";
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + user_id
        + "?access_token=" + access_token + "&callback=?";   

 
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $("div").append("<img src='"+data.data.profile_picture+"' />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <h2 class="fs-title">ENTER YOUR USERNAME</h2>
  <h3 class="fs-subtitle">type your instagram username below</h3>
  <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="Username" />
  <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value="Next" />
</fieldset>

<div>
  <!-- Profile Picture Showing Here -->
</div>
```

please help me.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: are you sure that you dont know how to get value from a text box using javascript or jquery? Not even googled?

Comment: Where is your submit button?

Comment: @JaredSmith why he needs a submit button as there is no form?

Comment: `var user_id =  $('#uid').val();`

Comment: @AnoopLL i searched hard but i can't get the right solution for that. finally i asked here. do you know a way to get user id from username. ?